# I am using Aspose Cell Api to find and replace values from excel sheet. I am using text file to define replacement of each variable

Tags: java, aspose-cells

I am doing this using java.Please help me with this.I define variables in test file and I am using text file for replacement but it is not executed.Kindly help me with this.I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound error in following code.
 import com.aspose.cells.*;

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by Amit on 7/4/2017.
     */
    public class CellExcel {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

            Workbook workbook = new Workbook( "//home//amit//Documents//test.xlsx");

            Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);

            // Specify the range where you want to search
    // Here the range is E3:H6
            CellArea area = CellArea.createCellArea("A1", "A20");

            // Specify Find options
            FindOptions opts = new FindOptions();
            opts.setLookInType(LookInType.VALUES);
            opts.setLookAtType(LookAtType.ENTIRE_CONTENT);
            opts.setRange(area);

            //////////////////////////

            Reader reader =
                    null;

            try {
                reader = new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream("//home//amit//Documents//demo.txt"));
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line = null;

            try {
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    lines.add(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            ////////////////////////

            Cell cell = null;


                for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                    String[] splitting = lines.get(i).split("\t");

                     String array1[] = new String[100];
                     String array2[] = new String[100];
                     array1[i] = splitting[0];
                     array2[i] = splitting[1];

                     System.out.println(array1[i]+"\t"+array2[i]);

                     for(int j = 0;j < 20;j++){
                    // Search the cell with value search within range
                    cell = worksheet.getCells().find(array1[i], cell, opts);

                             // If no such cell found, then break the loop
                    if (cell == null)
                        break;

                    // Replace the cell with value replace
                    cell.putValue(array2[i]);

                     }
                   // System.out.println(array1[i]);
                    //System.out.println(array2[i]);


                }

    // Save the workbook
            workbook.save("//home//amit//Documents//output.xlsx");
           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Success");
            System.out.println("Success");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to include the stacktrace. It will also show the exact place where you're accessing an array index out of bounds. Then you need to fix the code in that place somehow. You also seem to be indexing the arrays quite randomly with `i`, creating `100` sized arrays for no reason etc. It looks like you need to go through an array tutorial, as there are way too many basic mistakes in this code.

Comment: @Amit, this exception might not be because of Aspose.Cells but it might be due to the fact that you are accessing your array out of bounds. So please provide us your stack trace as requested by Kayaman. Thank you. Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following sample code. It is same as yours. I have tested the code with the sample Excel file and it generated the output Excel file successfully without any error.

I have attached the screenshot which shows three things

1. Test.xlsx
2. Output.xlsx
3. Demo.txt

These sample files were created by me to test your code. As you can see in the image, Output.xlsx file is correct as per Demo.txt.

[image]

Here is the sample runnable code which is same as yours except with little modifications for your reference.

**Java**

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(dirPath + "test.xlsx");

Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);

// Specify the range where you want to search
// Here the range is E3:H6
CellArea area = CellArea.createCellArea("A1", "A20");

// Specify Find options
FindOptions opts = new FindOptions();
opts.setLookInType(LookInType.VALUES);
opts.setLookAtType(LookAtType.ENTIRE_CONTENT);
opts.setRange(area);

//////////////////////////

Reader reader = null;

try {
    reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(dirPath + "demo.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
String line = null;

try {
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

////////////////////////

Cell cell = null;

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    String[] splitting = lines.get(i).split("\t");

    String array1[] = new String[100];
    String array2[] = new String[100];
    array1[i] = splitting[0];
    array2[i] = splitting[1];

    System.out.println(array1[i] + "\t" + array2[i]);

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {

        cell = worksheet.getCells().find(array1[i], cell, opts);

        // If no such cell found, then break the loop
        if (cell == null)
            break;

        // Replace the cell with value replace
        cell.putValue(array2[i]);

    }

}

// Save the workbook
workbook.save(dirPath + "Output.xlsx");
System.out.println("Success");
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose